# Maximum value from a list of lists and its index

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nested-lists

```
li = [[1,2], [2,3], [7,6]]
```

How can I find the max value and its index efficiently? Suppose for `li` I want:

```
max_value = 7

max_index = (2, 0)
```

I can do this as below:

```
max_value = 0
for row_idx, row in enumerate(alignment_matrix):    
    for col_idx, col in enumerate(row):
        if col > max_value:
            max_value = col
            max_index = (row_idx, col_idx)
```

But I need an efficient way without using too many unnecessary variables.

Comment: That's already a pretty efficient way. Starting with `max_value = None` would allow you to handle negative numbers, too, but otherwise I would be inclined to leave it as it is unless it turns out to be a significant bottleneck.

Comment: I expected something using less number of variables. Just to get this I used 6 extra local variables. It would be nice if I could reduce number of local variables here. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, though? The cost of them is pretty minimal, and the code is readable. Unless you find an actual performance problem, this is done; move on!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), you can express it more shortly:

```
max_value, max_index = max((x, (i, j))
                           for i, row in enumerate(li)
                           for j, x in enumerate(row))
```

But, time complexity is same because this one also uses nested loop.

**UPDATE**

As @jonrsharpe pointed, in the case of duplicate `max_value`s, above solution will give you the largest index at which the value found.

If that's not what you want, you can pass `key` function argument to `max` to customize the behavior:

```
max_value, max_index = max(((x, (i, j))
                            for i, row in enumerate(li)
                            for j, x in enumerate(row)),
                           key=lambda (x, (i, j)): (x, -i, -j))
```

Comment: Note that, in the case of duplicate `max_value`s, this will give you the *largest* index at which that value can be found (whether or not that's a good thing, I don't know!)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, You're right. Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like:

```
max(data, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Or, a more efficient alternative:

```
max(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Here's the time comparison:

```
In [11]: timeit.timeit('max(data, key=lambda x: x[0])', setup='import operator, random; data=[[random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)]')
Out[11]: 8.272005081176758

In [12]: timeit.timeit('max(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))', setup='import operator, random; data=[[random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(100)]')
Out[12]: 5.0041139125823975
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It neither gives the max value, nor does it give the index of the max value.